# regex expression with accurately string

Tags: regex, expression

i want to find  tag in middle text. but i want just the jquery.js script.

....

```
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

...

In other words, how i Found with regex expression just "`<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`"

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this regular expression?

```
<\s*script\s+src\s*=\s*"jquery.js".*<\/script>
```

https://regex101.com/r/qT7pF6/1

Comment: Thx,And if I have more content before "http://www.mysite.co,/js/jquery.js"?

Comment: Something like this:  `<\s*script\s+src\s*=\s*"(?:.+\/)?jquery.js".*<\/script>`

Comment: A better version: `<\s*script\s+src\s*=\s*"(?:[^\s]+\/)?jquery.js".*<\/script>` It does not allow white space between the first quote (") and the next word or any blank space in general on src path. Although I guess the code is correct and you are not doing a compiler (but I was bored: P). This is all. I hope I helped you. Thank you.